# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. after page load in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, exception, out-of-memory

I have a web form in asp.net that every time I try to access it, it throws the following exception

Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

It does enter the page load and finishes all the methods inside it, but once the page is supposed to be loaded, it throws the exception. (for now I'm trying it in localhost)

I'm not absolutely sure where the problem might be.
If you need a part of the example let me know.
Thanks in advance

asp

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="addRefundByStation.aspx.cs" Inherits="Stations_addRefundByStation" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="obout_Flyout2_NET" Namespace="OboutInc.Flyout2" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ew" Namespace="eWorld.UI" Assembly="eWorld.UI, Version=1.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24d65337282035f2" %>

Add Refund

```
    <meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0.25)" />
    <meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(Duration=0.25)" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
    <link href="../styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function cambiar()
        {
            __doPostBack('btnChange','');
        }

        function loadPage(url)
        {           
            var id = window.showModalDialog(url,'','dialogWidth:540px; dialogHeight:450px; toolbar:no; resizable:no; help:no; scroll:no; status:no;');
        }

        function viewCalendars() 
        {
            if (screen.width <= 1024)
            {
                if (document.getElementById('ddlDates').value == '3') 
                {
                    document.getElementById('divSpecificDates').style.display='inline'; 
                    document.getElementById('divRowBlank').style.display='inline'; 
                    document.getElementById('divSpace1024').style.display='inline'; 
                    document.getElementById('divResolution').style.display='inline';
                    document.getElementById('divSpace1024Dates').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('divResolutionWithoutFilter').style.display='none';
                }

                else 
                {
                    document.getElementById('divSpecificDates').style.display='none';     
                    document.getElementById('divRowBlank').style.display='none';          
                    document.getElementById('divSpace1024').style.display='inline'; 
                    document.getElementById('divSpace1024Dates').style.display='inline';
                    document.getElementById('divResolutionWithoutFilter').style.display='inline';
                }

                document.getElementById('divRowBlank').style.display='none';
            }

            else
            {
                document.getElementById('divResolution').style.display = 'none';

                if(document.getElementById('ddlDates').value == '3') 
                {
                    document.getElementById('divSpecificDates').style.display='inline'; 
                    document.getElementById('divRowBlank').style.display='inline'; 
                    document.getElementById('divSpace').style.display='none'; 
                    document.getElementById('divSpace1024').style.display='inline'; 
                }

                else 
                {
                    document.getElementById('divSpecificDates').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('divRowBlank').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('divSpace').style.display='inline'; 
                    document.getElementById('divSpace1024').style.display='inline';
                }
            }

            return;
        }

        function GoBack()
        {
            document.location.href = '../Stations/listRefunds.aspx?idStation=<% = Request["idStation"] %>';
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" onload="viewCalendars();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnIdStation" value="-1" />

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="smInvoice" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <table style="width:100%;position: absolute; top: 13px; left: 10px;" 
            cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td visible="false" style="width:75%;" valign="top" runat="server" id="tdConsumption">
                    <table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="leftSub" style="width:10px; height: 30px;" />

                            <td class="subTitle" style="width: 55%; height: 30px;">
                                Consumos -&nbsp;

                                <asp:Label ID="lblStation" runat="server">
                                </asp:Label>
                            </td>

                            <td style="text-align: right; height: 39px;" class="subTitle">
                                <a href="javascript:GoBack();" style="color:White; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;">
                                    <img alt="Regresar" src="../images/icons/arrow-Back.gif" />
                                    Regresar
                                </a>

                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnAdd" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/icons/plus.png" OnClick="imgBtnAdd_Click" />

                                <asp:Label ID="lblAdd" runat="server" Text="Agregar Consumo" Font-Size="12px" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="white" OnClick="imgBtnAdd_Click">
                                </asp:Label>
                            </td>

                            <td class="rightSub" style="width:10px; height: 30px;" />
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="leftTop" style="width:10px;" />
                            <td class="top" colspan="2" />
                            <td class="rightTop" style="width:10px;" />
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="left" style="width:10px;" />

                            <td class="generic" colspan="2">
                                Fecha del Estado de Cuenta:&nbsp;

                                <ew:CalendarPopup ID="cldDate" runat="server" JavascriptOnChangeFunction="javascript:cambiar();" >
                                </ew:CalendarPopup>

                                <br />
                                Buscar:&nbsp;

                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" onkeydown="javascript:ValidarEnter()" CssClass="tbox" Width="100px" ID="tbxSearch">
                                </asp:TextBox>

                                &nbsp;

                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvBeginDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbxBeginDate">
                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEndDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbxEndDate">
                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                Fechas:&nbsp;

                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDates" CssClass="tbox" runat="server">
                                </asp:DropDownList>

                                <div style="display: inline;" id="divSpace">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </div>

                                <div runat="server" id="divSpecificDates" style="display: none; width: 98%;">
                                    <div style="width: 80%; display: inline;">
                                    </div>

                                    Desde:&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                    <ew:CalendarPopup ID="tbxBeginDate" runat="server">
                                    </ew:CalendarPopup>

                                    <div style="display: none" id="divResolution">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td height="4px" />
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>

                                    <div style="display: inline;" id="divSpace1024Dates">
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </div>

                                    Hasta:&nbsp;

                                    <ew:CalendarPopup ID="tbxEndDate" runat="server" >
                                    </ew:CalendarPopup>
                                </div>

                                <div style="display: none" id="divRowBlank">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="4px" />
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                <asp:Button Text="Filtrar" CssClass="btn" runat="server" ID="btnFilter" OnClick="btnFilter_Click" />
                                <br />

                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Large" Text="Consumos Pendientes: ">
                                        </asp:Label>

                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalAmount" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Red">
                                        </asp:Label>

                                        <div>
                                        </div>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </td>

                            <td class="right" style="width:10px;" />
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="left" style="width:10px;" />

                            <td colspan="2" valign="top">
                                <asp:GridView ID="grvConsumption" runat="server" DataKeyNames="idConsumption" 
                                    AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="50" Width="98%" 
                                    CssClass="borders" HeaderStyle-CssClass="subT" AllowSorting="true" 
                                    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="txtB" RowStyle-CssClass="txtA"
                                    OnPageIndexChanging="grvConsumption_PageIndexChanging" 
                                    OnSorting="grvConsumption_Sorting" OnRowDataBound="grvConsumption_RowDataBound">
                                    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="texto" />

                                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                        <asp:Literal ID="ltNoInformationFound" runat="server">
                                            No se encontraron Consumos
                                        </asp:Literal>
                                    </EmptyDataTemplate>

                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" Visible="false">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblConsumption" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.idConsumption") %>'>
                                                </asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" Visible="false">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblTypeDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.TypeDesc") %>'>
                                                </asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="ID" DataField="idConsumption" SortExpression="idConsumption" HtmlEncode="False" />
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Tarjeta" DataField="cardCode" SortExpression="cardCode" HtmlEncode="False" />

                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Fecha" SortExpression="dateCreated">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <%# string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",((DateTime)(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "dateCreated"))))%>
                                                <br>
                                                <%# ((DateTime)(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "dateCreated"))).ToString("hh:mm tt") %>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Cantidad" DataField="quantity" SortExpression="quantity" DataFormatString="{0:##,##0.000}" HtmlEncode="False" />
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Descripci&oacute;n" DataField="description" SortExpression="description" />
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="P. Unitario" DataField="price" SortExpression="price" DataFormatString="{0:#,$##0.00}" HtmlEncode="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Total" DataField="total" SortExpression="total" DataFormatString="{0:C}" HtmlEncode="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />

                                        <asp:TemplateField itemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Iva" SortExpression="tax">
                                            <ItemTemplate >
                                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "tax").ToString() + " %" %>                                               
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
                                            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="false" />

                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ckbChange" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>

                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                Sel. todos
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxSelectAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="cbxSelectAll_OnCheckedChanged" />
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Image ID="imgCoupon" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/icons/coupon.gif" Visible='<%# Eval("couponConsumption") %>' />

                                                <cc1:Flyout ID="Flyout1" runat="server"  Position="MIDDLE_LEFT" AttachTo="imgCoupon" Visible='<%# Eval("couponConsumption") %>'>
                                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="tblEdit" runat="server" style="width: 100px">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="leftSub" />

                                                            <td class="subTitle">
                                                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" ForeColor="white" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12px" Text="Vales">
                                                                </asp:Label>
                                                            </td>

                                                            <td class="subTitle" align="left" />
                                                            <td class="rightSub" />
                                                        </tr>

                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="leftTop" />
                                                            <td class="top" colspan="2" />
                                                            <td class="rightTop" />
                                                        </tr>

                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="left" />

                                                            <td valign="middle" align="center" colspan="2" style="background-color:White;">
                                                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("couponConsumtion") %>'>
                                                                </asp:Label>
                                                            </td>

                                                            <td class="right" />
                                                        </tr>

                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="leftBtm" style="height: 22px" />
                                                            <td class="btm" colspan="2" style="height: 22px" />
                                                            <td class="rightBtm" style="height: 22px" />
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table> 
                                                </cc1:Flyout>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>

                                    <EditRowStyle CssClass="txtB" />
                                    <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="tboxCombo" ForeColor="DarkGoldenrod" BorderWidth="0" />
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </td>

                            <td class="right" style="width:10px;" />
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="leftBtm" style="width:10px;" />
                            <td class="btm" colspan="2" />
                            <td class="rightBtm" style="width:10px;" />
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnConsumption" value="-1" />
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnSort" />
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnTotal" value="-1" />
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnTax" value="-1" />
    </form>
</body>
```

cs

//varios Usings

public partial class Stations_addRefundByStation : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //imgBtnSaveRefund.Attributes.Add("onclick", base.DisableButton(imgBtnSaveRefund, true, true).ToString());

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        dblSubtotal = 0;

        if (Request["idStation"] != null)
        {
            int intIdStation = int.Parse(Request["idStation"]);
            hdnIdStation.Value = intIdStation.ToString();

            Station objStation = new Station(intIdStation);
            aCancel.HRef = "../Stations/listRefunds.aspx?idStation=" + intIdStation;

            Dates();

            lblStation.Text = objStation.shortname;
            tbxPayMethod.Text = objStation.payMethod;
            tbx4Digits.Text = objStation.fourDigitAccount;

            tbxBeginDate.SelectedDate = tbxEndDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
            this.EnableViewState = true;
            loadData();
            loadDdlDates();
            rememberOldFiltersValues();
        }

        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Administration/detailStation.aspx");
        }
    }
}

private void loadData()
{
    //dtConsumption = Consumption.listTableByClient(client.id);
    dtConsumption = Consumption.GetConsumptionTable(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-100), DateTime.Now.AddYears(100), -1, int.Parse(hdnIdStation.Value), false);
    ViewState.Add(VSN.dtListConsumptions, dtConsumption);

    DataColumn[] keys = new DataColumn[1];
    keys[0] = (DataColumn)dtConsumption.Columns[0];
    dtConsumption.PrimaryKey = keys;
    loadGridView();

    dtSource = dtConsumption.Clone();
    ViewState.Add(VSN.dtSource, dtSource);

    lblQuantity.Text = dtSource.Rows.Count.ToString();
    lblSubTotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C");
    lblTax.Text = dblTax.ToString("C");
    lblTotal.Text = dblTotal.ToString("C");
    lblCommissionAmount.Text = dblCommissionAmount.ToString("C");
    lblCommissionTaxAmount.Text = dblCommissionTaxAmount.ToString("C");
    lblPendingAmount.Text = dblPendingAmount.ToString("C");

    if (dtConsumption.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        lblTotalAmount.Text = double.Parse(dtConsumption.Compute("sum(total)", string.Empty).ToString()).ToString("C");
    }

    else
    {
        lblTotalAmount.Text = "$0.00";
    }
}

private void loadDdlDates()
{
    ddlDates.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Seleccionar...", "-1"));
    ddlDates.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Este mes", "1"));
    ddlDates.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("Este año a la Fecha", "2"));
    ddlDates.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem("Fechas Específicas", "3"));
    ddlDates.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript:viewCalendars();");
}

private void loadGridView()
{
    grvConsumption.DataSource = dtConsumption;
    grvConsumption.DataBind();
}

private void Dates()
{
    DateTime dates = cldDate.SelectedDate;

    if (dates.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        tbxDueDate.SelectedDate = dates.AddDays(2);
    }

    else if (dates.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        tbxDueDate.SelectedDate = dates.AddDays(1);
    }

    else
    {
        tbxDueDate.SelectedDate = dates;
    }
}

protected DatesParams GetDates()
{
    return new DatesParams().GetDatesParams(tbxBeginDate.SelectedDate, tbxEndDate.SelectedDate, ddlDates.SelectedValue);
}

private void rememberOldFiltersValues()
{
    if (Session[SN.filtersRefundByStation] != null)
    {
        filterUtility filters = (filterUtility)Session[SN.filtersRefundByStation];
        ddlDates.SelectedValue = filters.idDatesFilter.ToString();
        tbxSearch.Text = filters.searchCriteria;

        if (filters.idDatesFilter != -1)
        {
            tbxBeginDate.SelectedDate = filters.startDate;
            tbxEndDate.SelectedDate = filters.endDate;
        }
    }
}

public static DataTable dataViewAsDataTable(DataView dv)
{
    DataTable dt = dv.Table.Clone();

    foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
    {
        dt.ImportRow(drv.Row);
    }

    return dt;
}

protected DatesCriteria getCriteria()
{
    return (new DatesCriteria()).getDatesCriteria(tbxBeginDate.SelectedDate, tbxEndDate.SelectedDate, ddlDates.SelectedValue);
}
protected void imgBtnAdd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //Not used for now
}

protected void grvConsumption_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gridView = (GridView)sender;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        int cellIndex = -1;

        foreach (DataControlField field in gridView.Columns)
        {
            if (field.SortExpression == "quantity" || field.SortExpression == "description" || field.SortExpression == "price" || field.SortExpression == "total" || field.SortExpression == "dateCreated" || field.SortExpression == "tax" || field.SortExpression == "idConsumption" || field.SortExpression == "name" || field.SortExpression == "cardCode")
            {
                cellIndex = gridView.Columns.IndexOf(field);
                e.Row.Cells[cellIndex].CssClass = "headerstyle";

                if (hdnSort.Value.StartsWith(field.SortExpression))
                {
                    if (hdnSort.Value.EndsWith("asc"))
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[cellIndex].CssClass = "sortascheaderstyle";
                    }

                    else if (hdnSort.Value.EndsWith("desc"))
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[cellIndex].CssClass = "sortdescheaderstyle";
                    }
                }
            }

            if (field.SortExpression == "")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[gridView.Columns.IndexOf(field)].CssClass = "subT";
            }
        }
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label lblConsumption = (Label)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("lblConsumption");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.className='mouseOverWithOutHand'");

        if (e.Row.RowIndex % 2 == 0 && lblConsumption.Text != hdnConsumption.Value)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.className='txtA'");
        }

        else if (lblConsumption.Text != hdnConsumption.Value)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.className='txtB'");
        }

        if (lblConsumption.Text == hdnConsumption.Value)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.className='subT2'");
            e.Row.CssClass = "subT2";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `If you need a part of the example let me know`, of course we would need some code to look at. But honestly, what you need to do, is comment out all of the code you can and start un-commenting it along the way. You will find the culprit a lot faster that way (even if there's a lot of code) -trust me.

Comment: My psychic sense tells me that object somewhere is causing some memory leakage, however without the code for us to analyze we can't help you.

Comment: Are there any infinite loops / circular references occurring in Page_Load? that would definitely cause the above exception...

Comment: I have added the code part, I hope it's not so confusing

Comment: this question has *way* too much code. You need to try to isolate the problem a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are creating three different copies of dtConsumption.  That seems like the most likely culprit.  Especially considering it looks like you're requesting 200 years worth of data.

So you pull 100 years in the past to 100 years in the future:

```
dtConsumption = Consumption.GetConsumptionTable(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-100), DateTime.Now.AddYears(100), -1, int.Parse(hdnIdStation.Value), false);
```

Add it to the ViewState:

```
ViewState.Add(VSN.dtListConsumptions, dtConsumption);
```

Clone it and add it to the ViewState again:

```
dtSource = dtConsumption.Clone();
ViewState.Add(VSN.dtSource, dtSource);
```

And then bind it to your GridView (whose contents is stored in the Viewstate):

```
grvConsumption.DataSource = dtConsumption;
grvConsumption.DataBind();
```

Depending on available memory, and the size of this DataTable, I could definitely see that causing an out of memory exception.

Comment: dtConsumption returns at around 35,000 rows, with 20 columns at least

Comment: @Victor Small columns (`bit`) or large columns (like `nvarchar(max)`)?  Either way, you should probably not pull all of it at once, but just as much as you need.

Comment: @Victor Also, imagine this being in a production environment, where more than one user could request that page at once.  You're easily getting hundreds of thousands of rows loaded into memory at that point - if not millions.

Comment: yes... I'm really concerned about that...
right now I'm trying to use less resources...
I got rid of the datatables and using only sessions.
and I'm trying to return less columns on my SP

Comment: That sounds like a good start, @Victor.  Good luck!